# Can php divide the page into small block and gradually appear?

Tags: php, load

Can php divide the page into small block and gradually appear? 
I divided my main page into several small blocks, like:

```
<?php 
include('header.php');
<div id="content">
<!-- some content -->
</div>
include('partone.php');
include('parttwo.php');
include('partthree.php');
include('footer.php');
?>
```

I need open the page, first load `header.php`, `div#content`, `footer.php`, then gradually loaded `partone.php`, `parttwo.php`, `partthree.php`. Is there a way could do that? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code to look like the following

```
<?php 
include('header.php');
?>
<div id="content">
<!-- some content -->
</div>
<div id="partOne"></div>
<div id="partTwo"></div>
<div id="partThree"></div>
<?php
include('footer.php');
?>
```

Then make 3 ajax requests to load in partone.php, parttwo.php and partthree.php to their respecitve divs in the above code. Plenty of tutorials on how to do this via all the different javascript frameworks out there. Personally I use jquery, but you can use whatever is your preference for this.

Comment: include partone.php, parttwo.php and partthree.php into div, then use ajax requests is the feasible method.

Answer (score 4):

PHP is executed server side, so your code will include all the files listed, and send the entire output to the client computer at once.

If you want only parts of the page to appear at a time, try enclosing them in `div`s and use JavaScript.

Comment: Not quite true. You can use output buffing and ob_flush() to force the earlier parts of the page to be pushed to the browser before page generation is complete at the server end.

Comment: @David Gillen, sorry, it is hard to understand for me. I still want to read some tutorial code. thanks.

Comment: @David - I never knew that. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should be using javascript to do this.

Have a look at the [jQuery get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) method.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you're after: http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/load-content-while-scrolling-with-jquery/

Demo: http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/dnspinger/

Comment: I know this plungin, but I am not sure whether it can use in php. As I know, php files should load all the files listed, then out put the page at the same time.